# To get pagination in my wiget custom post type list

Tags: wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have get the custom post type by category in widget. Now i want to paginate those post if those more than 10 posts.For that i tried with this code

```
<ul class="posts-list">
    <?php
            $cats = get_the_category();
            $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
            $paged= isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
        query_posts(array ( 'category_name' => $cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged));
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            // do whatever you want 
    ?>
    <li>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <p><strong>posted on</strong> <?php the_time(' F jS, Y') ?> <strong>by</strong> <?php the_author(); ?></p>
        <p><strong>Posted in</strong> <span><?php print_r($cat_name); ?></span></p> 
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </li>
<?php
$pag_args1 = array(
    'format'   => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'  => $paged,
    'total'    => 3,
    'add_args' => array( 'paged' => $paged)
);
echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 ); ?>
</ul>
```

But i cant get the exact result.

Comment: hello, you got answer already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181796/pagination-for-my-custom-post-type-in-widget

Comment: But here i used the  query_posts instead of get_posts function. Thats why i cant understand and the previous one is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try like the below

```
<ul class="posts-list">
    <?php
            $cats = get_the_category();
            $cat_name = $cats[0]->name;
            if ( get_query_var('paged') )
          { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
          elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
         else { $paged = 1; } 
        query_posts(array ( 'category_name' => $cat_name, 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'paged' => $paged));
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            // do whatever you want 
    ?>
    <li>
        <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
        <p><strong>posted on</strong> <?php the_time(' F jS, Y') ?> <strong>by</strong> <?php the_author(); ?></p>
        <p><strong>Posted in</strong> <span><?php print_r($cat_name); ?></span></p> 
        <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </li>
<?php
$pag_args1 = array(
    'format'   => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'  => $paged,
    'total'    => 3,
    'add_args' => array( 'paged' => $paged)
);
echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 ); ?>
</ul>
```